# Custom sorting by two parameters not working correctly

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

```java
public List<List<Integer>> demo(int[][] buildings) {
    List<List<Integer>> tracker = new ArrayList<>();
    int pointer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
        tracker.add(Arrays.asList(buildings[i][0], -buildings[i][2]));
        tracker.add(Arrays.asList(buildings[i][1], buildings[i][2]));
    }
    Collections.sort(tracker, (a, b) -> {
        if (a.get(0) != b.get(0)) {
            return a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
        } else {
            return a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1));
        }
    });
    return tracker;
}
```

When I input:

```
[[1,10001,10000],[2,10001,9999],[3,10001,9998]]
```

the output I get is:

```
[[1,-10000],[2,-9999],[3,-9998],[10001,10000],[10001,9999],[10001,9998]]
```

This is not the output that I expect, because my sorting rule is supposed to be when `10001 == 10001` then the ones with smaller second coordinates should be arranged at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is Integer caching. For the low numbers, the Integer is cached so `!=` works. For the large numbers, new `Integer`s are used. Use Integer.equals to check for equality.

Change:

```
if(a.get(0) != b.get(0))
```

Into:

```
if( a.get(0).equals(b.get(0)) )
```

Otherwise you're comparing the reference not the value.

Another way would be to use the helper methods of the Comparator class.

```
Comparator.<List<Integer>>comparing( list -> list.get(0) ).thenComparing(list-> list.get(1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66053674/5221149) is spot on.

Here is an alternative way to fix it. Don't compare values twice, i.e. don't use both `equals()` *and* `compareTo()`:

```java
Collections.sort(tracker, (a, b) -> {
    int cmp = a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1));
    }
    return cmp;
} );
```

Even easier solution:

```java
Collections.sort(tracker, Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0))
                                .thenComparing(x -> x.get(1)));
```

Depending on the version of the compiler, it may need a "hint" to know what `x` is. Either of these should do it, neither is better than the other.

```java
Collections.sort(tracker, Comparator.<List<Integer>>comparing(x -> x.get(0))
                                               .thenComparing(x -> x.get(1)));
```

```java
Collections.sort(tracker, Comparator.comparing((List<Integer> x) -> x.get(0))
                                .thenComparing(x -> x.get(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing object in Java always use equals or compareTo (accordingly).

Instead of:

```
   if(a.get(0) != b.get(0)){ // <---- THIS IS WRONG
        return a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
    }
```

You can reused already the `compareTo` result of:

```
a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
```

namely :

```
    int result = a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
    return result == 0 ? a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1)) : result;
```

Moreover instead of `Collection.sort` you can simply used tracker.sort and  replaced the comparison logic with a Comparator chain:

```
tracker.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((List<Integer> a) -> a.get(0))
                       .thenComparingInt(a -> a.get(1)));
```

A running example:

```
public class A {

    public static List<List<Integer>> demo(int[][] buildings) {
        List<List<Integer>> tracker = new ArrayList<>();
        int pointer = 0;
        for (int[] building : buildings) {
            tracker.add(Arrays.asList(building[0], -building[2]));
            tracker.add(Arrays.asList(building[1], building[2]));
        }
        tracker.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((List<Integer> a) -> a.get(0))
               .thenComparingInt(a -> a.get(1)));
        return tracker;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] x = new int[][]{{1,10001,10000},{2,10001,9999},{3,10001,9998}};
        List<List<Integer>> demo = demo(x);
        demo.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, -10000]
[2, -9999]
[3, -9998]
[10001, 9998]
[10001, 9999]
[10001, 10000]
```